# 2 dimension array is not looping in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have an snippet that i am trying to loop 2 times on an array like below :

```
     $rules = Rule::get();
        $segments = [];
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            $segments['segment = "basic"']['serviceType']= $rule->segment;
            foreach($rule->steps as $key => $value) {
                $segments['segment = "basic"'][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $segments;
```

so what i am expecting to get from that code is like below :

```
 'segment = "BASIC"'     => [
                'serviceType = "3"'  => [
                  'item1' => 1,
                  'item2' => 2
                ],
                'serviceType = "2"'  => [
                  'item1' => 1,
                  'item2' => 2
                ],
                'serviceType = "1"'  => [
                  'item1' => 1,
                  'item2' => 2
                ],
```

but what i get is like below

```
^ array:1 [
  "segment = "basic"" => array:3 [
    "serviceType" => "1"
    "item1" => 1
    "item1" => 2
  ]
]
```

so what i want is that the array inside the the `segment = "basic" repeats as the count of` Rule` model i know that my code is returning 5 instance of model but i guess at some point the code is overwriting the array instead of looping it . thanks in advance

Comment: The code you have presented doesn't seem like it would output what you say you get. The loop defines a `'serviceType'` key here: `$segments['segment = "basic"']['serviceType']= $rule->segment;`, but that key is not present at that level in the array you get.

Comment: i am sorry i didnt get you but i am sure that this is the output of the current code

Comment: my only problem is that the secound part which should loop and give me 4 arrays returns only 1

Comment: You would also benefit from creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know where these values come from so it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Side note: The array keys you use are very confusing, $segments['basic'] ... Would make your code more readable. Same thing for the serviceType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not put the items in the servicetype part of your array:
Does this do the trick?

```
$rules = Rule::get();
        $segments = [];
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            $segments['segment = "basic"']['serviceType = "'. $rule->segment . '"']= [] ;
            foreach($rule->steps as $key => $value) {
                $segments['segment = "basic"']['serviceType = "'. $rule->segment . '"'][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $segments;
```